# How to move label's text right to left,when a character hides in left it shows on right?

Tags: c#, label, controls

Here is my key code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Scroller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i, j;
        bool k = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                  
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Time:"+ System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            i--;
            j = i + this.Width;
            if (i < this.Width && i > 0)
            {
                label1.Left = i;
            }
            else
            if (i < 0 && k == false)
            {
                label1.Left = i;
                k = true;
            }
            else
            if (i < 0 && k == true)
            {
                label1.Left = j;
                k = false;
            }

            if (i < 0 - label1.Width)
            {
                i = this.Width - label1.Width;
            }
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Time:"+  System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            i = this.Width - label1.Width;
            label1.Left = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The effect that I want to make is the whole time string move right to left. When a pixel of the text disappear on the left side (because it is out of the form's left border),the pixel will shows on the right side.

In other words, the effect can't be make by delete the first character of string and append it to the last.

I knew that it will be easier to use two label to do it. Set one's location in the form and hide the other right by the form. Move them in the same time.

When the first label hit the left border of the form, the second hit the right border of the form. And the first one move out, the second move in. Until the second totally move in, reset their x location.

But I just want to use one label. So I chose to quickly switch the label's location, and try to "cheat" user's eye. **The problem is when the label switch between left and right, it flash very obviously.** Even though I set timer's interval below 20,the problem still exist.

Could you help me dissolve the flash problem or enlighten me other ways which can just use one label and one timer to make the effect I need?

Thanks. If I didn't describer my problem clear enough or need more code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can work out the flashing problem changing the label's location in a windows form.

Another solution would be to set the label width the same size as the form width, make the label text fill all the width using spaces and make the timer always get the last character and put it on the beginning of the string.

Sample code below.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = label1.Text.Substring(label1.Text.Length - 1) + label1.Text.Remove(label1.Text.Length - 1);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The total spaces required to fill the form vary from form.width and the initial label.text.width
    // Width | Spaces
    //  177  |   13
    //  228  |   30
    //  297  |   53
    //  318  |   60

    // The spacesEnd = 60 work for a form with width 319
    int spacesBegin = 0, spacesEnd = 60;

    label1.Text = "Time:" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    label1.AutoSize = false;
    label1.Left = -3;
    label1.Width = this.Width - 1;
    label1.Height = 15;
    label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

    for (int i = 0; i < spacesBegin; i++)
        label1.Text = " " + label1.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < spacesEnd; i++)
        label1.Text += " ";

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer.Interval = 50;
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: I ran your code. And set label's width to 319.Here are some issues:1.When the time text meet the right side, it will stuck few ms. 2.Because the text's minimum movement is base on per space, and a space's width equal several pixels. That will make the text's moving not very smooth. 3.When the xx/ xx:xx:xx disappear on right side, the same content won't show up on the left side. Are there any better solution? Maybe use padding rather than space will work better?